# RTMPE Video Player (With Skip)

Tags: objective-c, flash, video, red5, rtmp

I have successfully created a Cocoa app using RtmpDump for a video stream.
Currently, the application merely downloads the file to the user’s desktop and
they must play it in VLC.

However, I wish to create a custom RTMPE player that will allow the user to skip
forward and backward at will. I understand that XBMC has this functionality, but
I was wondering if there was any open source library that I could use (and if
so, any pointers on how to use them). Also, is there a client for librtmp that
is written in order to download a stream starting at certain segments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was any open source library that I could use (and if
>   so, any pointers on how to use them).

Yes, you can use the
[LibRtmp library](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html).

[FFplay](http://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html) already
has 
[support for RTMPE](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html)
protocol.

> Also, is there a client for librtmp that is written in order to download a
>   stream starting at certain segments?

RtmpDump can already do this with the
[`--start`](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/rtmpdump.1.html)
param.

Comment: RTMPDump with the --start is exactly what I'm looking for I think (I'll have to create a custom video player though). I'll also look into FFPlay and see if this fits my description.